# Why background css property breaks down in to background-image while updating the height of the background div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html with inline css styling like this:

```
<div class="bgdiv" style="background: url('http://wallpaper.pickywallpapers.com/1366x768/colorful-circles-and-drops.jpg') local center center no-repeat transparent;
background-size:100% 100%;
width: 400px;height:400px"> I am some dummy text. </div>
```

Which renders correctly, but if I change the height of the div to `500px` via javascript it breaks down into several components of background like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.bgdiv').css('height', '500px');
});
```

Final/output inline css style:

```
background-image: url(http://wallpaper.pickywallpapers.com/1366x768/colorful-circles-and-drops.jpg); 
background-attachment: local; 
background-color: transparent; 
background-size: 100%; 
width: 400px; 
height: 500px; 
background-position: 50% 50%; 
background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
```

If you notice I applied `background` but now it is `background-image` and the biggest problem is `background-size:100%` however I applied `background-size:100% 100%` which is unexpected and I don't want it to change.

Here is the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/pu7WR/1/

Please inspect to see the changes in css. I am not sure if this is the expected behavior but `background-size:100%` is breaking things I want it to be `background-size:100% 100%`

Note: I can not use a class here. And I know, I can change the `background-size` after updating the height.

But why so? Why it is getting updated in the first place?

Let me know I can provide further details. (I ll try to provide better title for the question)

Comment: the `background-size` property is shortened to `100%` because it's the same value for both dimensions. It is the same as `100% 100%`. I don't understand what the problem is here though?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: Actually, `100%` is not the same as `100% 100%`. `100%` corresponds to `100% auto` instead, which is different. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size

Comment: @BoltClock I agree with you. It causes problem in some cases, when you change the height/width dynamically background wont stretch to fill the area.

Comment: @BoltClock you are correct. I assumed it worked in the same way as `margin` etc. where if one value is supplied it is given to all dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

That's normal. `background` is a shorthand property that allows you to set the individual properties at once. Internally, the browser parses this shorthand property and applies its values to each of the individual properties it represents.

That's why something like this would cause "unexpected" results:

```css
#elem {
    background-color: red;
    background:url(/my/awesome/image.png) no-repeat scroll left top;
}
```

The element will appear with no red background colour, because the `background` shorthand property overrides it with `transparent` (the default assumed value if you don't specify it).

Comment: My problem is `background-size:100%`, Why does it change? When I styled  it with `background-size:100% 100%`

Comment: @edward: Because it's one of the properties that's being set by the shorthand.

Comment: But if you notice I am adding the background-size after the shorthand then it should override. right?

Comment: I'm not sure about it. I wouldn't count on it, anyway. Especially not in an inline attribute. Instead, why not use all shorthand? `background: url(...) local center center no-repeat transparent / 100% 100%` Or all longhand, defining each one individually?

Comment: @edward: Ah, I didn't see that. That's indeed the case. By the way, I'm not sure if `background-attachment: local` can be used yet - I'm on Firefox which doesn't support it so I may be seeing something different.

Comment: Yeah, I know that about attachment local, we have handled it, FF nightly builds supports it though :)

Comment: @edward: Oh sweet, that is awesome news.

Answer (score 0):

This actually does seem like a bug. If you set the values to different numbers then it will always retain it, but if you use an exact number twice it will use just the one, which is obviously a problem because that means the other will be auto, which will give a different result to what you want. The workaround I found was setting one to 100% and the other to 99.99% which is obviously a bit of a hack, but it does work:

http://jsfiddle.net/pu7WR/4/

```
<div class="bgdiv" style="background-image: url(http://wallpaper.pickywallpapers.com/1366x768/colorful-circles-and-drops.jpg); background-attachment: local; background-color: transparent;   background-size: 99.99% 99.99%; height: 500px; width: 400px; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
    I am some dummy text.
</div>
```

Another option (if you are able) is to wrap the content in it's own div and set the height on that one instead:
http://jsfiddle.net/pu7WR/5/

```
<div class="bgdiv" style="background-image: url(http://wallpaper.pickywallpapers.com/1366x768/colorful-circles-and-drops.jpg); background-attachment: local; background-color: transparent;   background-size: 100% 100%; height: 500px; width: 400px; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
    <div class="contentDiv">I am some dummy text.</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.contentDiv').css('height','500px');
});
```

Comment: If you inspect the div in your demo, you would notice that the output background-size is 100% and not `100% 100%`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, realized that when I went back and looked at it. I've updated my answer, hopefully one will work for you.